# button disappear when hovered over

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover

i have this image:

[image]

so if you can see i have this image and i have created onMouseEnter and onMouseOut so the red cross appears when i get the mouse inside and disappear when the mouse is outside the image. however, this red cross also is a button and has a functionality and whenever i hover on the button it disappears even though i set the state right. my problem is that the button disappear and i don't want that cz it has functionality:

code.js:

```
    const handleOnMouseHover = () => {
            const isToggle = true
            setToggleDiv(isToggle)
        }

        const handleOnMouseOut = () => {
            const isToggle = false
            setToggleDiv(isToggle)
        }

<div>
            <h3>preview items</h3>
            <div className="image">
                <img src={Url}  onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseHover} onMouseOut={handleOnMouseOut}  />
                <div>{photoTitle}</div>
                {toggleDiv === true?
                <div className="delete" type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(photoId)}>X</div>
                :null}
            </div>
            </div>
```

code.css:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }

  .image .delete {
    background-color: red;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the onMouseEnter on the div with class "image" instead of the img itself. 
Because when you hover the button then the hover from image is removed and onMouseEnter will not work.
Hope it helps

Comment: i honestly did but also when i hover on the button itself it also disappear i don't know why

Comment: Try to use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` in place of `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseOut` 
and make sure to use it on parent div of the image.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to move your `onMouseEnter` `onMouseOut` to the container of image and button, like that:

```
<h3>preview items</h3>
<div className="image" onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseHover} onMouseOut={handleOnMouseOut}>
    <img src={Url}  />
    <div>{photoTitle}</div>
    {toggleDiv === true?
    <div className="delete" type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(photoId)}>X</div>
    :null}
</div>
```

Comment: i honestly did but still the same it also diasppears and i don't know why

Comment: You are right, so I would suggest using css for it. I have prepared code for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cache-4x43h?file=/index.css